# Distribution for hitting times for simple random walk

Tags: probability-theory

Suppose that $X_n$ is a sequence of IID RVs, each $x_n$ having the same distributions as $X$ where $$P(X=1)=P(X=-1)=\frac{1}{2}$$. Define $S_0:=0$, $S_n:=X_1+...+X_n$ and set $T:=\text{inf}\{n:S_n=1\}$. The filtration is the natural filtration. Define a Martingale: $$M^\theta_n=(\text{sech}\theta)^ne^{\theta S_n}$$.
Since T is a stopping time, and $M^\theta$ is a martingale, we have

$$E[M_{T\land n}^\theta]=1$$.

Now, we insist $\theta>0$ , the Martingale is bounded and we define for $T=\infty$, $M_{T\land n}^\theta=0$. Hence, we can make the following $$E[M_T^\theta]=1$$ and hence$$E[(\text{sech}\theta)^T]=e^{-\theta}$$.

Now they tried to deduce the probability distribution for $T$ in the following way:

Put $\alpha=\text{sech}\theta$,$$E[\alpha^T]=\sum\alpha^nP(T=n)=e^{-\theta}=\alpha^{-1}(1-\sqrt{1-\alpha^2})$$ and hence $$P(T=2m-1)=(-1)^{m+1}\binom{\frac{1}{2}}{m}$$.

**Question:** How does $P(T=2m-1)=(-1)^{m+1}\binom{\frac{1}{2}}{m}$ from the last equality?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use Newton's generalisation of the binomial theorem which says that for $x\in \mathbb{R}$,

$$(1+y)^x=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\binom{x}{k}y^k$$

where I have used $\binom{x}{k}$ is the binomial coefficient $$\binom{x}{k}=\frac{x(x-1)\cdots (x-k+1)}{k!}$$ which takes the value 1 when $k=0$.

Apply this theorem to $(1-\alpha^2)^{\frac{1}{2}}$ in the expression
$$f=\alpha^{-1}(1-\sqrt{1-\alpha^2})$$

$$(1-\alpha^2)^{\frac{1}{2}}=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\binom{\frac{1}{2}}{k} (-\alpha^2)^k=1+\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\binom{\frac{1}{2}}{k} (-1)^k \alpha^{2k}$$

So then $$f=\alpha^{-1}(1-\sqrt{1-\alpha^2})=\alpha^{-1}\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\binom{\frac{1}{2}}{k}(-1)^{k+1}\alpha^{2k}=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\binom{\frac{1}{2}}{k}  (-1)^{k+1}\alpha^{2k-1}$$

Since $P(T=2k-1)$ is the coefficient of $\alpha^{2k-1}$ in your expansion, you have your result that

$$P(T=2m-1)=(-1)^{m+1}\binom{\frac{1}{2}}{m}$$.